# What happens if someone else uses my disqus shortname?

Tags: disqus

What happens if someone else uses my disqus_shortname?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone else uses your registered shortname on their site, all their comments will appear in your moderation panel.

To avoid this, we suggest adding your domain name to the Trusted Domains section of your Disqus admin panel. This can be found under Settings > General > Trusted Domains. This will prevent other users from loading your shortname on their site.

Comment: This has moved it's now under ```Settings > Advanced > Trusted Domains```